# Trouble making images and title align horizontally

Tags: html, css

Html HERE---

```
<div id="uktvHeader">
<nobr>
    <img id="uktvLogo" src="images/uktv_logo.jpg">
    <h3 id="uktvTitle"> UKTV Promo Campaigns Final Workflow </h3>
    <img id="farmLogo" src="images/Trans_Logo.png" alt="Farm Logo">
</nobr>
</div>
```

CSS HERE---
[image]

```
#uktvHeader{
    height: 70px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    max-width: 650px;


}
    #uktvLogo {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;


}
    #farmLogo {
    float: right;
    margin-top: -70px;
    width: 100px;

}
    #uktvTitle {
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 50px;
```

The image is how it looks now and I am okay with that but I thought there must be a better way to horizontally align the first image, title and last image.

Currently I am applying a negative px value to margin-top on the last image which seems wonky to me. If I don't do this then the 'farm group' image sits just below the first image and h3 text. I would like a more graceful way of aligning these items.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: wrap the three in a div with display set to flex. That's the most graceful way of doing that which I have come across.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
nobr > * {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

That should do it. CSS is self explanatory.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/27q0nLo8/2/

Comment: So simple, I knew it had to be. Thanks for adding the example as well, very useful!

Comment: @Wine.Merchant No problem! Good luck selling your wine! :3

Comment: If you could perhaps answer one more question, is there a way to create a small space between the title and each of the two images? To make it appear a little neater.

Comment: @Wine.Merchant Try giving your h3 a little margin on the sides:   nobr > h3 { margin: 0 1em;}